# How to find the limit of this particular function?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to compute $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4+3x^2}-2}$$

I know the answer is $\dfrac{4}{3}$, but how to prove it?

Comment: Please also explain what you have tried and where you got stuck.  This is a learning opportunity, even if within minutes somebody will just post the correct answer...

Answer (score 6):

Hint (assuming the question was supposed to be as $x\rightarrow 0$):

$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4+3x^2}-2}&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4+3x^2}-2}\times\frac{\sqrt{4+3x^2}+2}{\sqrt{4+3x^2}+2}
\\&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^2\left(\sqrt{4+3x^2}+2\right)}{3x^2}
\\&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sqrt{4+3x^2}+2}{3}
\end{align}$$